SQL Trino: count unique words
I'm using SQL Trino trying to count the unique words (ignore any numbers) in a string column.
The column values look like this:
MEDIA_SOCIAL,2336;IDEOLOGY,1442;KIDNAP,601;MED...
I have tried this:
count(distinct v2themes) as themes

which gives me TrinoQueryError(type=INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES, name=EXCEEDED_GLOBAL_MEMORY_LIMIT...

Are you really storing semicolon separated strings in a single column?

It seems that your query is significantly more complicated than the fragment shown. In addition, the DBMS is trying to sort by column v2themes - and this is a resource-expensive operation. Show the entire query, the table structure and its size.

First of all, you need to find the way to extract the words and ignore the numbers since they are combined in the same column. So you need to figure out what the data type of the column is. Try typeof(v2themes) function to see the data type. If it's just string, you can simply use split(v2themes,',')[1] to extract the words(I highly likely doubt it since the error saying insufficient resource). So if it is something else like json, you may use json function to get the words first.
